# how to see the communication between client and server (string form)

Tags: networking, sniffing, client-server

I have a client-server application. The problem is the server is not able to support as many client as being mentioned in the specs or as being claimed by the provider.

What i am trying to is to replace the server with my own implementation removing the current limitation and also scaling it to a bit.

But in order to maintain connection between the client and server i have to see how communication is taking place.

I have tried to find the source but got no success.

Hence now i am looking forward to track the communication and then create a mock to establish the connection between my server and client.

So why i am here is because i want o know is it possible to look into the communication taking place if so then how?

PS: I have already tried to sniff data packet using wireshark but the problem is it is showing only hex data packet of a portion of communication which is difficult to track and decode

Comment: If you can't handle hex, you might have a little trouble reverse engineering a networked protocol. Understanding hex really is fundamental, because not everything has a convenient ASCII representation. The more you do, the easier it gets.

Comment: I can understand Hex but the problem is i don't know the character-encoding scheme it is following. thus a unable to reproduce the same communication request and responses in my own server implimentation

Answer (score 0):

> I can understand Hex but the problem is i don't know the character-encoding scheme it is following.

Maybe it's not using *any* character-encoding scheme; maybe it's encoding stuff as binary numbers, not text characters.

If you know the protocol, you could write a dissector for Wireshark (or give information about the protocol to somebody who can write a dissector), and use Wireshark+that dissector to see the traffic.

If you *don't* know the protocol, you'll have to reverse-engineer it, which is a lot of work, and may involve looking at binary data rather than plain text.

Comment: "If you don't know the protocol, you'll have to reverse-engineer it, which is a lot of work, and may involve looking at binary data rather than plain text." Thats what actually i am up to, and for that i was looking for any help or any pointer anyone may give